# How to get the indexpath based on sections in uitableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, nsindexpath

Hi i am working with Tableview i am facing one issue.My table like number of sections with in that number of rows now in my cellForRowAtIndexPath when i fetch my array like below

```
NSInteger rowNumber = 0;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
        rowNumber += [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
    }

    rowNumber += indexPath.row;
NSString *messageStatus = [[_messageArray1 objectAtIndex:rowNumber] chatStatus];
NSString *messageID1=[[_messageArray1 objectAtIndex:rowNumber] messageID];
    NSString *messageString=[[_messageArray1 objectAtIndex:rowNumber] msg];
```

but it is showing suppose section 2 row 2 but in rownumber it is showing 2 only but i need like section 1 rows +section 2 row number.in case if i give indexpath.row it is showing same like rownumber.
how to acheive it please help me

Comment: Consider to design the data source with nested arrays to mirror the index path structure

Comment: sorry i didn't get you

Comment: It seems you have one flat array for all items. My suggestion is to use one array for each section and a base array containing the section arrays, for example `let sectionArray = mainArray[indexPath.section]; let message = sectionArray [indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
NSInteger rowNumber = 0;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
    rowNumber += [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}

rowNumber += indexPath.row;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:
[[sender superview] tag]];
```